# How to establish RabbitMQ connection with php code while DB,PHP etc is running as docker container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, docker-compose, docker-container

I have an application running with multiple containers using docker-compose.yml. Also there is a custom directory (Which contains my custom code) which is mapped to docker containers in the docker-compose.yml.

With this custom directory I need to use RabbitMQ. So the question is how to incorporate it with complete application as DB is now a separate container.

I understand that one way can be using RabbitMQ container and modifying yml for it. Which is not preferred solution for me. Please suggest other ways to achieve it. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What do u mean by 'With this custom directory I need to use RabbitMQ.'. What does rabbitmq need from this directory.

Comment: @yamenk, apart from images one image is providing option to place our custom code which is a volume and mapped in yml. In this custom code we have implementation for RabbitMQ